# PyErr_Set* twice

Tags: python, c, exception, python-c-extension

Is it safe to call `PyErr_Set*` to override an exception? According to the docs, [`PySequence_Fast`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/sequence.html#PySequence_Fast) raises a `TypeError` with the `const char *` message argument supplied to it if there's an error. Would it be safe to call `PyErr_SetObject` after `PySequence_Fast` raises an error?

Example:

```
static PyObject * myfunc(PyObject * self, PyObject * args) {
    PyObject * pyobj;
    PyObject * pyseq;
    PyObject * message;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &pyobj)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    pyseq = PySequence_Fast(pyobj, "");
    if (pyseq == NULL) {
        message = PyString_FromFormat("argument is a '%s', not a sequence.", pyobj->ob_type->tp_name);
        PyErr_SetObject(PyExc_TypeError, message);
        Py_XDECREF(message);
        return NULL;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to "Python/errors.c" from the Python 2.7.2 source code, `PyErr_SetObject()` calls `PyErr_Restore()` which `Py_XDECREF()`s any old exception state variables before setting the new ones. So yes, it is safe to override an existing exception. Just be aware that you are completely overriding the previous exception.